# OrderBy record ASC in two columns

Tags: c#, form-load

I'm trying to OrderBy in form loud my columns in windows application. I try to use this code:

```
using (SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM remaining WHERE username=@username and status=@status and company_status=@company_status ORDER BY call_case ASC , Payment_Status ASC", sqlconn))
```

Is that the right way to do it?

What I'm looking for is to OrderBy (call_case) ASC, and when call_case= (2-Answer) OrderBy (Payment_Status) ASC .

```
 (  call_case ), ( Payment_Status )

   null    ,    null 

   1-No Answer ,    null

   2-answer    ,    1-Promise Payment

   2-answer    ,    2-Have Problem

   2-answer    ,    3-Reject Payment

   3- not Exist ,      null
```

> i have a note it my be help the text start with number like 1-No Answer , 2-answer , 3- not Exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression along with `ORDER BY` like

```
SELECT * FROM remaining 
WHERE username=@username 
and status=@status 
and company_status=@company_status 
ORDER BY      
   case when call_case='Answer' then 0 else 1 end ASC,      
   Payment_Status ASC
```

Comment: is that CASE give me what i looking for ?

Comment: @ahmed Why not give a try and see

Comment: `using (SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM remaining WHERE username = @username and status = @status and company_status = @company_status ORDER BY case when call_case = '2-Answer' then 0 else 1 end ASC Payment_Status ASC", sqlconn)) ` i try that and it give to me (Incorrect syntax near 'Payment_Status)

Comment: is `end ASC, Payment_Status` what the way

Comment: i have a note it my be help the text start with number like 1-No Answer , 2-answer , 3- not Exist

Comment: @ahmed per your post *What I'm looking for is to sort (call_case) ASC, and when call_case=Answer sort (Payment_Status) ASC* ... Please modify your question to include other condition for `OrderBy`